# Retrieving store records

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a JSON like this.

```
{
    "children":[
        {"name": "subdivision1","id": "subdiv1","type": "subdiv","children":[
            {"name": "Scheme1","id": "scheme1","type": "scheme","children":[
                {"name": "Nathuji","id": "nathuji","type": "datalogger","leaf":true},
                { "name": "Tarsang","id": "tarsang","type": "datalogger","leaf":true},
                { "name": "Mithapur","id": "mithapur","type": "datalogger","leaf":true},
                { "name": "Samali","id": "samali","type": "datalogger","leaf":true}]},
            {"name": "Scheme2","id": "scheme2","type": "scheme","children":[
                { "name": "Bhunidra","belongsto": "scheme2","id": "bhunidra","type": "datalogger","leaf":true},
                { "name": "Chhogala","belongsto": "scheme2","id": "chhogala","type": "datalogger","leaf":true}]
                }]},
        {"name": "subdivision2","id": "subdiv2","type": "subdiv","children":[
            {"name": "Scheme3","id": "scheme3","type": "scheme","children":[
                { "name": "Thana Savli","belongsto": "scheme3","id": "thanasavli","type": "datalogger","leaf":true},
                { "name": "Padardi","belongsto": "scheme3","id": "padardi","type": "datalogger","leaf":true}]
                }]}]}
```

Model like this.

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.model.dataloggerhierarchymodel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name','id','type'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'data/allschemes.json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'children'
        }
    }
});
```

Store like this.

```
Ext.define('DemoApp.store.dataloggerhierarchystore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'DemoApp.model.dataloggerhierarchymodel',
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load:function(){
            console.log('Datalogger Tree store loaded');
        }
    },
    root: {
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

I am accessing it in the controller like,

```
var schemesStore = this.getDataloggerhierarchystoreStore();
        if(schemesStore == null || schemesStore == undefined){
            console.log('Store Undefined');
        }
        for(var i = 0; i< schemesStore.count();i++)
            {
                console.log('Record - '+schemesStore[i].get('id'));
            };

        schemesStore.each(function(currentRecord){
            console.log(currentRecord.get('id'));
        });
```

I am displaying it in a tree panel and it works fine. Now I want to access each record from the store.
But I am getting the error `count()` is not a function. The same in case of `totalCount()`, `each()`. What am I missing here? How can I access individual records from the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Ext.data.TreeStore` is not a subclass of `Ext.data.Store`. It doesn't have all of the methods that normal stores do. In order to access data, you have to access the root node by using `getRootNode()` and using the methods defined in `Ext.data.NodeInterface`.

NodeInterface provides the `cascadeBy()` method as an equivalent of `each()`, and you'll have to use it to code your own `count()` method.

Comment: But with `NodeInterface` how can I access each fields? Say if I want to retrieve `id` and `name`, how can I obtain through the current `NodeInterface`?

Comment: I mean similar to `get()` function in normal stores?

Comment: The methods in `NodeInterface` are used to decorate your model. So you can still use `get()` on individual nodes. Basically, it turns your records into tree nodes.

Comment: I got what I desired. Thnx. I'd +2 or 3 if I could.. :)